# Disable cross-domain ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, cross-domain, cors

Is there any way to disable cross-domain ajax request?

Lets say there are two domains: ***mywebsite.com*** and ***hackerswebsite.com***. On the ***mywebsite.com*** there is a website which contains javascript with AJAX function which sends data to ***hackerswebsite.com***. All I want is to prevent this and allow only sending AJAX request to *mywebsite.com* domain.

I know there is something like *"Same origin policy"* but what I understand it works on the second domain and can prevent connections from other domains.

To be more precise, lets say that I have a website where users can run their own javascript. If they can write their own scripts they can get any data from DOM document and send it asynchronously to their own server which will accept data from my domain. For example login name. Am i right?

Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm just trying to understand this security policy thing.

Comment: So they can make a GET request and send the same information!  `img.src="asdf.php?myInfo=goesHere";`

Comment: You don't need users to be able to run their script on your page in order to acquire any data visible in your DOM/BOM. They can just see that data anyway, and transfer it anywhere they want.

Comment: I want to give them possibility to run their own scipts. Not to see data of the page, just to run their own stuff.

Comment: ANY method of accessing exposed data can be used by the client in any way they wish. Once it's out the door, you no longer control it. If you want to protect something, put it behind a login.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you want a [content security policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) (CSP) to restrict what resources and Ajax destinations the page can and can't use.

The *same-origin policy* is designed to prevent websites from *reading* credentialed responses from a third party (e.g., I load `evil.com`, and that site instructs my browser to fetch my online bank statements, using my `bank.com` cookies). The SOP is *not* intended to prevent users or sites from *sending* data wherever they like.

The site's CSP is intended to whitelist access to resources, in the event that either:

1. the site is compromised by an XSS attack and suddenly behaves in ways you didn't anticipate, or
2. the site runs content supplied by user A on a browser owned by user B, and that content needs to be sandboxed.

To be clear, the danger in case #2 is not that a user can run his *own* JavaScript, but that a user might run some *other* user's script.

An example CSP might be:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; frame-src 'none'; object-src 'none';
```

This will block any attempt to load iframes or plugins, and it restricts all other resource loads (including images, scripts,  stylesheets, and Ajax requests) to the current origin. If you want to allow plugins or iframes, you can remove either or those directives and they will fall back to the `default-src` directive. You can use the `connect-src` directive to limit Ajax specifically.

Note also that if you lets users run arbitrary scripts, you will likely still have serious problems (e.g., rewriting the page with misleading content), even with a very restrictive CSP taking care of cross-origin network requests.

Comment: So if i understand that correctly, this security policy will prevent AJAX connection to any other domain except my own? I'm not worrying about retrieve data, I worry about unattended sending data to any other server.

Comment: @Katan87 That is correct; the `'self'` in my example CSP means "this origin only". Any attempt to load a resource or send an Ajax request to another origin will fail.

Comment: That is all i wanted to know. Now i'll give it a try :) I know about other problems and that's not a big deal in my case. Great answer!